# How to print something to user in Django?

Tags: django

When a Django website goes live, I know it is a bad idea to use Python's print function... However, I want to print output (maybe through a terminal/command line) that the users of my website can see when the Django website goes live. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: The problem is not entirely clear to me. `print` does not print something to a user, it writes it to the standard output channel.

Comment: Right, Question is how do I output information to the user?

Comment: You want *their* bash terminals to print? Or you want the website to display some text?

Comment: Their bash terminals to print.

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all. You show things to the user by displaying them on the web page that they have requested.